# Nao consigo indentificar o erro no Android

Tags: android

Se alguém souber o esta errado.

> 04-09 13:45:42.403: E/AndroidRuntime(5902): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   04-09 13:45:42.403: E/AndroidRuntime(5902):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.teste.teste2/com.teste.teste2}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 04-09 13:45:42.403:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(5902):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
>   04-09 13:45:42.403: E/AndroidRuntime(5902):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>   04-09 13:45:42.403: E/AndroidRuntime(5902):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125) 04-09
>   13:45:42.403: E/AndroidRuntime(5902):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>   04-09 13:45:42.403: E/AndroidRuntime(5902):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 04-09
>   13:45:42.403: E/AndroidRuntime(5902):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 04-09 13:45:42.403:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(5902):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 04-09
>   13:45:42.403: E/AndroidRuntime(5902):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 04-09
>   13:45:42.403: E/AndroidRuntime(5902):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 04-09 13:45:42.403:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(5902):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
>   04-09 13:45:42.403: E/AndroidRuntime(5902):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 04-09
>   13:45:42.403: E/AndroidRuntime(5902):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 04-09 13:45:42.403:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(5902): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   04-09 13:45:42.403: E/AndroidRuntime(5902):   at
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:80)
>   04-09 13:45:42.403: E/AndroidRuntime(5902):   at
>   android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:182) 04-09
>   13:45:42.403: E/AndroidRuntime(5902):     at
>   com.teste.teste2.Teste.(Matriz.java:21) 04-09 13:45:42.403:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(5902):   at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native
>   Method) 04-09 13:45:42.403: E/AndroidRuntime(5902):   at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429) 04-09 13:45:42.403:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(5902):   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
>   04-09 13:45:42.403: E/AndroidRuntime(5902):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
>   04-09 13:45:42.403: E/AndroidRuntime(5902):   ... 11 more

***outro erro da mesma forma não encontro erro.***

> 04-09 14:54:20.053: E/AndroidRuntime(7097):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
>   04-09 14:54:20.053: E/AndroidRuntime(7097):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>   04-09 14:54:20.053: E/AndroidRuntime(7097):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125) 04-09
>   14:54:20.053: E/AndroidRuntime(7097):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>   04-09 14:54:20.053: E/AndroidRuntime(7097):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 04-09
>   14:54:20.053: E/AndroidRuntime(7097):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 04-09 14:54:20.053:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(7097):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 04-09
>   14:54:20.053: E/AndroidRuntime(7097):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 04-09
>   14:54:20.053: E/AndroidRuntime(7097):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 04-09 14:54:20.053:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(7097):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
>   04-09 14:54:20.053: E/AndroidRuntime(7097):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 04-09
>   14:54:20.053: E/AndroidRuntime(7097):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 04-09 14:54:20.053:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(7097): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   04-09 14:54:20.053: E/AndroidRuntime(7097):   at
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:80)
>   04-09 14:54:20.053: E/AndroidRuntime(7097):   at
>   android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:182) 04-09
>   14:54:20.053: E/AndroidRuntime(7097):     at
>   com.teste.teste2.Teste.(Matriz.java:26) 04-09 14:54:20.053:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(7097):   at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native
>   Method) 04-09 14:54:20.053: E/AndroidRuntime(7097):   at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429) 04-09 14:54:20.053:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(7097):   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
>   04-09 14:54:20.053: E/AndroidRuntime(7097):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
>   04-09 14:54:20.053: E/AndroidRuntime(7097):   ... 11 more

Comment: Você tem um `NullPointerException`, pelo que entendi ele está na classe `Matriz` na linha 21.

Comment: @Math depois de consertar o 1º primeiro erro surge esse erro que coloquei na pergunta se você poder dar uma olhada valeu.

Comment: Aparentemente é o mesmo erro na mesma classe, porém mudou para a linha 26. Talvez seja o caso de você adicionar o seu código na sua pergunta para tentarmos identificar a causa raiz do problema.